# How to restart heroku server within golang app?

Tags: go, heroku

I am trying to restart heroku server conditionally. SO I wrote following code for restarting heroku server

```
go func() {
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

            cmd := exec.Command("heroku", "restart")
            b, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("\n======> error restarting server: %v", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("\n======>  server restart response : %s", string(b))
        }()
```

But first time it is restarting successfully, from second time onwards, it is not restarting. Is there any other way to restart or Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Your code above runs the `heroku` command once only. How are you timing it or calling it periodically? Is it in a loop? Please post more of your code.

Comment: needs more details

Comment: this is not periodically. this piece of the code calls conditionally (after a certain condition). Please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

```
go func() {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 10)

    for range t.C{
        cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c","heroku restart")
        var outb, errb bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &outb
        cmd.Stderr = &errb
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("\n======> error restarting server: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("\n======>  server restart response : %s, %s", outb.String(), errb.String())
    }
}()
```

check https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker

`NewTicker returns a new Ticker containing a channel that will send the time with a period specified by the duration argument. It adjusts the intervals or drops ticks to make up for slow receivers. The duration d must be greater than zero; if not, NewTicker will panic. Stop the ticker to release associated resources.`

Comment: but main problem here is to restart heroku gracefully. heroku server not restarting second time with these changes

Comment: @ravindradevagiri does `heroku restart` function as expected when you run it manually in the terminal?